# getimagesize() não funciona no Plesk + Windows

Tags: php, windows, plesk

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
$info = getimagesize($this->tmp_name);
```

Ao analisar a variável **$info**, verifiquei que estava em branco.

- Verifiquei que a biblioteca GD estava instalada.
- Verifiquei as permissões de escrita nas pastas.
- Verifiquei a variável `$this->tmp_name`, o seu valor era *C:\Windows\Temp\php85CD.tmp*
- Verifiquei que a diretiva **open_basedir** era diferente: *D:\Inetpub\vhosts\meusite.com\httpdocs* (não deveria ser *C:\Windows\Temp\*?)

Se não, qual poderá ser o problema, uma vez que o upload não funciona?

Answer (score 2):

Vamos por partes:

1. getimagesize() espera que o primeiro argumento seja um arquivo de imagem. Informar o arquivo temporário pode ser o causador do problema;

   1.1. E isso não significa que a função é quem esteja impedindo o upload. Para verificar se houve erro no upload você deve verificar o valor do índice **error** em **$_FILES**:

   ```
   if( $_FILES['upload']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK ) {

       // Sucesso! Trabalhe com move_uploaded_file()

   } else {

       // Uh-oh :(
   }
   ```
2. **$info** estar "branco" provavelmente significa que você ecoou um FALSE, valor retornado por getimagesize() quando esta falha.

   2.1. Se falhou e retornou FALSE e você não viu nenhum erro, seus alertas estão desativados ou muito baixos para exibir o Warning:

   ```
   error_rerpoting( E_ALL );
   ini_set( 'display_errors', TRUE );
   ```
3. **open_basedir** é diferente de [upload_tmp_dir](http://www.php.net/upload_tmp_dir).

   O valor recebido está correto pois restringe que funções de manipulamento de arquivo operem sobre arquivos fora do *directory root*.

Comment: Verifiquei o ambiente e é Windows Server/IIS. Será alguma limitação/configuração por não ser o Apache?